# How to display .dcm images using GPURenderDemo and vtkGDCMImageReader

Tags: rendering, visualization

I am getting a problem in executing GPURenderDemo file in VTK volume rendering. I am using vtkGDCMReader to read the image. On running the code it gives an error "exited with code 1"

Answer (score 0):

right click on your project name and go to properties->Debugging->command argument 
now type -DICOM "complete path upto your dicome file" click apply..
now you will be able to see dicome image.